# Selecting record from db (sqlite3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table of users and before inserting into it values I need to check if a user already exists, how can I do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods/exists%3F) or maybe, a dynamic method like `find_or_create_by_...`.

Answer (score 0):

> *need to check if a user already exists*

first you need to define what a 'user already exists' means -> probably unique by email address?

see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#uniqueness

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :email, :uniqueness => true
end
```

> The validation happens by performing an SQL query into the model’s
>   table, searching for an existing record with the same value in that
>   attribute. It does not create a uniqueness constraint in the database.

Use in conjunction with a unique constraint in the db is probably your best bet; create a migration with

```
change_table :users do |t|
  t.index :email, :unique => true
end
```